# TypeScript : Ajax call call always calling Error rather than success on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, typescript

In typescript I have a DataAccess Class so that all Ajax calls are routed through a single object to save repetition of code in a lot of places within my application.

In using this approach I have needed to use call backs to get the response back to the calling class so that the success and error can be handled accordingly.

This is the typescript

```
 ajaxCall(retVal, retError) {

        $.ajax({
            type: this.callType,
            data: this.dataObject,
            dataType: this.dataType,
            url: this.url,
            contentType: this.contentType,
            traditional: this.traditional,
            async: this._async,
            error:  retError,
            success: retVal
        });
    }
```

This is the compiled Javascript

```
AjaxDataAccessLayer.prototype.ajaxCall = function (retVal, retError) {
   $.ajax({
   type: this.callType,
   data: this.dataObject,
   dataType: this.dataType,
   url: this.url,
   contentType: this.contentType,
   traditional: this.traditional,
   async: this._async,
   error: retError,
   success: retVal
  });
};
return AjaxDataAccessLayer;
```

This calls through to the ASP.Net MVC controllers perfectly fine, however the problem that I have is regardless of Success or Error the call back is always retError.

This is the calling Typescript

```
var _this = this;
        var dataAccess = new DataAccess.AjaxDataAccessLayer(Fe.Upsm.Enums.AjaxCallType.Post,
            Fe.Upsm.Enums.AjaxDataType.json,
            "../../PrintQueue/DeletePrintQueueItems",
            jsonObj);

        dataAccess.ajaxCall(data => {
            // success
            new Fe.Upsm.Head().showGlobalNotification("Selected Items Deleted");
            _this.refreshPrintQueueGrid();
            (window as any).parent.refreshOperatorPrintQueueCount();
        }, xhr => {
            // failure
            alert("An Error Occurred. Failed to update Note");
        });
```

When stepping through and looking at this the Status is OK and the response is 200.

[image]

So, Problem (as mentioned above) always calling xhr \ retError regardless of success.

Question: How do I get it to go into the right call back?

Comment: You can use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) which is tailor designed for Angular 5 for sending AJAX requests to the server instead of importing jQuery again.

Comment: Im not using Angular

Comment: This is ASP.Net MVC, Telerik \ Kendo UI, and Typescript

Comment: What datatype are you expecting? Because probably the error is not in the HTTP request, which as you say finishes correctly, but while processing the response. Why don't you change the error callback you pass to `ajaxCall` to get the error thrown?: `(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {...}` This way you can show us **exactly** what the error is

Comment: @OscarPaz good idea! looks like im getting a json parse error thats being returned, which is odd because nothing in the back has changed, and the only difference is the code has been changed from JavaScript to Typescript. Its pretty much a direct 1:1 replacement on 99% of the calls

Comment: I suspected something like that, because in your image, you can see that `responseText` is an empty string, and `JSON.parse('')` throws an error. You should check the response from the backend

Comment: @OscarPaz spot on! bloody controller was at fault. Looks like I have about 78 controllers to fix now because they are not actually returning any json, but when it was not typescript it was just going... yup... im good... ill take this on...

Comment: I'll add that as a the answer, then :-)

Comment: And you sir will get the points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error handler, you were not passing all the parameters, so you are only checking whether the request finished successfully. However, there can be errors after that, like when the response is processed. You can handle errors betters like this:

```
dataAccess.ajaxCall(data => {
    // success
    new Fe.Upsm.Head().showGlobalNotification("Selected Items Deleted");
    _this.refreshPrintQueueGrid();
    (window as any).parent.refreshOperatorPrintQueueCount();
}, (xhr, errorText, errorThrown => {
    // failure
    console.log(xhr, errorTest, errorThrown);
    alert("An Error Occurred. Failed to update Note");
});
```

Based on the discoveries using this method, the error is that your controllers are returning empty responses, so you're getting an exception when jQuery tries to parse them, because an empty string is not valid JSON.